# How to show running time in terminal?

Tags: linux

I am using Python for a while and I learned that by some method like timeit() I can estimate the running time of my programe.

But, is it any way that when my programe finished in the terminal, it also print out the running time?! (any terminal command do that?!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following:

> $ time your_programm

the output is:

> $ time sleep 1
>
> real    0m1.002s
>
> user    0m0.000s
>
> sys     0m0.000s

showing how much time was spent in kernel and user space and the total time spent.

Answer (score 3):

The `time` command does exactly that.